# Behaviour of onNext and onComplete

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have an Observable that does something without the need to emit a value. Also I have a list of objects I want the Observable to work with. So for all elements in this list: doSomething()

```
Observable.from(uris)
        .flatMap(new Func1<Uri, Observable<Void>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Void> call(Uri uri) {
                return createDoSomethingObservable(uri);
            }
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(new Observer<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.d(TAG, "completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "next");
            }
        });
```

And the method that creates the Observable:

```
Observable<Void> createDoSomethingObservable(final Uri uri) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Void> subscriber) {
            //doSomething
            subscriber.onNext(null);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}
```

Now when I run this with a List with 3 elements I get:

```
next
next
next
completed
```

which is good, because that is what I wanted, but I don't know why it's working. First I started to just call onComplete, because in the end the observable does its job and completes. But then of course onNext is never called on the subscriber. The same goes for the other way round.

So my questions are:

1. Why is onComplete only called for the last list element?
2. Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onComplete` is called for the last element because that's when the earliest observable in the chain (`from(uris)`) has finished.

It's expected that your observables emitted from `flatMap` will call `onComplete`. Once that's done (and `call` has returned), then the next emission from `from` can be worked on. Once `from` has finished emitting observables, it calls `onComplete` and the chain is finished, effectively.

Answer (score 6):

I think, that small code helps you to understand behavior of `onNext( )` and  `onComplete()`.
Suppose, you have an `List<Uri>`. Let's transform it to `Observable<Uri>` **manually**.

```
public static Observable<Uri> getUries(List<Uri> uriList){
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Uri> subscriber) {
            for(Uri uri : uriList){
                subscriber.onNext(uri);
            }

            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}
```

Or using Lambda expressions:

```
public static Observable<Uri> getUries(List<Uri> uriList){
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        for(Uri uri : uriList){
            subscriber.onNext(uri);
        }

        subscriber.onCompleted();
    });
}
```

As you can see, we are iterating input list, and call `onNext( )` for every element, and when we finished transforming our `List` to `Observable`, we called `onComplete()`

**P.S.**
This code just a demonstration, please, **never use it** to transfor `List` to `Observable`. Use operator `Observable.from()` for it.

**UPDATE**:

Operator `from( )` implementation:

```
...
while (true) {
    if (o.isUnsubscribed()) {
        return;
    } else if (it.hasNext()) {
        o.onNext(it.next());
    } else if (!o.isUnsubscribed()) {
        o.onCompleted();
        return;
    } else {
        // is unsubscribed
        return;
    }
}
...
```

link:https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/OnSubscribeFromIterable.java#L75-L87

Answer (score 2):

`onComplete` (same as `onError`) is called only once during observable chain, it is the way that rxjava is implemented

I think that your approach is correct, so better way is not needed.